# Copy Data from one worksheet on another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to copy data from one workbook to another. After some browsing on the internet this is the code i found and it produces a run-time error 1004

```
Sub Name_Transfer()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDestination As Workbook

'open the source workbook and select the source sheet
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open( _
    Filename:="C:\TestFolder\2013 Cockpit Chart.xls")

'Set the destition workbook variable
Set wbDestination = Workbooks("U:\my documents\ATM Platform 2013\Advanced Team Management.xlsm")

'copy the source range
wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B4").Copy

'paste the value at E9
wbDestination.Sheets("DataStore").Range("A4:B6").Value = _
wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B4").Value

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

What is causing the 1004 error? Can it be fixed? or is there a far better way to be doing this?

Comment: Is the destination workbook already open?

Comment: No it has been closed.

Comment: Now you are missing the `.Open`. See the comment in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to mention this was being done in Excel 2007...

The reason behind the 1004 error was it was looking for a .xls file not a xlsx file

so the code should of looked like this

```
    'open the source workbook and select the source sheet
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open( _
    Filename:="C:\TestFolder\2013 Cockpit Chart.xlsx")
```

To close the file i just used

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Or as Siddharth so rightly said to use:

```
wbSource.close savechanges:= false
```

Thanks for your help contributors... I probably would of never seen this without all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Number of rows in source do not match with number of rows in destination.

Try this

```
wbDestination.Sheets("Delivery").Range("A4:B6").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

or

```
wbDestination.Sheets("DataStore").Range("A4:B6").Value = _
wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B4").Value
```

Also specify the path for

```
Set wbDestination = Workbooks("Advanced Team Management.xlsm")
```

like you did for `wbSource` in case `Advanced Team Management.xlsm` is closed.

Comment: It Doesn't stop at a specific point as soon as it tries to run it brings up a 1004 error.

Comment: Did you do everything as I have mentioned int he post above?

Comment: I've done all your suggestions yet still get a 1004 run-time error.

Comment: I hope you did `Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open("C:\SomePath\Advanced Team Management.xlsm")`

Comment: Yeah i did i forgot to add it back in on here when i edited it.. sorry for the delay i was on lunch. Im still getting the 1004 error.

Comment: I figured out where it was going wrong....

i accidently put .xls instead of .xlsx 

However it now copies and pastes the info but leaves the last workbook open.... any suggestions on how i could make this script close the book as soon as its opened and copied the data?

Comment: (posting from phone) i am out at the moment and wont be frequent in replying... to close the workbook you have to use `wbSource.close savechanges:= false`

Comment: Thanks Siddharth the source close was far better than the way i was doing it... the wait time for the file to close was a bit tedious. 

Thanks for all your help.